# Integration question measure theory

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For the function

$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
          \infty & \text{if $x=0$} \\
          1/x    & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q} \smallsetminus 0$} \\
          0      & \text{Otherwise}
        \end{cases}
$$
with domain $E = [0; 2]$ compute $\int f dm$

Could I please get some insight into doing this problem? I'm completely lost with measure theory and the material that I have is poor.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure $0$, the function is equal to zero almost everywhere; recall that if $f = g$ almost everywhere, then $\int_E f dm = \int_E g dm$ for all measurable sets $E$.

Comment: Perhaps Chen's lecture notes ["Introduction to Lebesgue Integration"](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnilifolder/lnili.html) are of help.